# How to rerun a the script when an error occured?

Tags: php, xml, urlretrieve

I have written a script that search for values in xml file. This files I retrieve online via the following code

```
# Reads entire file into a string
    $result = file_get_contents($xml_link);
    # Returns the xml string into an object
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

But the xml are somethimes are big with as consequence that I got the following error Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded. 
I have adapted the ini.php files to max_exucution time set to a 360 seconds but I still got the same error.

I have two options in mind.

- If this error occurs run the line again. But I couldn't find anything online (I am probably searching with wrong searchterms). Is there a possibility to run the line where the error occurs again?
- Save the xml files temporary local and search for the information in this way and remove in the end of the process. Here , I have no idea how to remove them after retrieving all data? And would this actually solve the problem? Because my script still needs to search through the xml file? Will it not take the same amount of time?

Comment: Why don't you try using CronJobs instead to ensure that user interface is not blocked for a longer period of time in order to keep the minimum expected user experience and execute time-consuming tasks?

Comment: I don't now anything about CronJobs. I found the following set_time_limit(0); But when I used it, I still got the same error. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used these two lines in my script the problem was solved.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
set_time_limit(0);
```